# Cygwin bash prompt not returned after starting servers

Tags: bash, cygwin

When I start servers using ant command, bash prompt does not get returned. Prompt is available only if I press Ctrl+Z or stops servers from another cygwin shell. 
I'm using cygwin 1.7.13-1

cygwin.batch has following env variables set

```
bash --login -i
set SHELLOPTS=igncr
set CYGWIN=nodoswarning
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing  1.7.15-1 version fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this documentation related to Cygwin](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#cygwin) and the section below it on [running Ant as a background process](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#background).

Probably something like:

```
ant </dev/null &
```

Comment: I have already tried appending & to start ant in the background and this returns process Id but immediately after that server starts printing out messages of startup and after completion of server startup prompt is not returned. Only if I press Ctrl Z or exception is thrown by the server, I get the prompt back

Comment: Thanks Dennis for the answer. I uninstalled this version and installed version  1.7.15-1 which has fixed the problem.